# CakePHP recursive not working with conditions

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a problem with querying associated data from a Model in CakePHP. I wrote an example to show the behavior:

TestController.php:

```
class TestController extends AppController
{

    public $uses = array(
        'User',
        'Upload',
        'Detail'

    );

    public function test(){
        $result = $this->Upload->find('all', array(
                'recursive' => 2,
                'conditions' => array('Detail.id' => 1)
        ));

        print_r($result);
    }

}
```

Upload.php:

```
class Upload extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Detail.php:

```
class Detail extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
}
```

User.php:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $hasOne = 'Detail';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Upload' => array(
            'className' => 'Upload',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        )
    );

}
```

When I remove the condition I get back an array with Details included. But with the condition I get the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Detail.id' in 'where clause'
```

Looking at the SQL Queries it seems like he is not joining the tables correctly when I add the condition. Without the condition he is joining all three tables.

Is this a bug in CakePHP or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: even though associations of models are in place, that doesn't mean cake will magically make a join for every condition you add. If you search for "Upload", you will *only* get that table (if you use containable behaviour, you can only still use conditions for the Upload table). For doing what you want to do, check [joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables). Also, keep in mind that you will have to do 2 joins, since Upload -> User -> Detail

Comment: If I remove "hasMany" in User (which is not needed for that query) then I only have "belongsTo" and "hasOne" connections. Your link says: "In CakePHP, some associations (belongsTo and hasOne) perform automatic joins to retrieve data".

Comment: yes, but your Upload model doesn't have a direct association with Detail, so the magic join won't happen. And also you need recursion -1 as the link says

Comment: Doesn't recursion -1 mean "Dont do any (automatic) joins" and 2 "Fetch for each Upload the associated User and its Detail"?

Comment: Correct.  If you're doing manual joins like Nunser is talking about, then you'll want to turn off recursive, or else weird things might happen due to automatic joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a bug with CakePHP.  It's simply the way it's designed, using conditions during a find on associated models will often create an invalid query.  You should be using containable behavior or manually joining to use conditions on associated models.

Also, I suspect that you will not get the results you are looking for doing this way anyways.  CakePHP by default uses left joins.  Therefore, your results will not be limited by those associated with the desired Detail ID, but rather, it will get all uploads, all users associated with those uploads, and then only those details associated with those users that have the correct ID.  The simplest way then to get what you're probably looking for is to do the query from the opposite direction:

```
$result = $this->Detail->find('all', array(
            'recursive' => 2,
            'conditions' => array('Detail.id' => 1)
    ));
```

EDIT:  If you do want to do left joins, then make your query this way:

```
$result = $this->Upload->find('all', array(
            'contain' => array('User' => array('Detail' => array('conditions' => array('Detail.id' => 1))),
    ));
```

Comment: No I actually want to get the Uploads with left joined Users and left joined details. This is used as an export for all Uploads.

Comment: Gotcha.  I've updated my answer with an example for how to use containable behavior then.

Comment: It works. Even though I am disappointed of cake that this does not work automatically. In cake 3 it looks way better though..

Comment: You really shouldn't be using recursive anyway.  It's not recommended nor ideal.  Containable is always the better method.